# memcached php extension memcached.sess_remove_failed

Tags: php, memcached

If `memcached.sess_remove_failed = 1`

and a server fails; I understand that it will not be used. But when it comes back up; does it automatically get added back? I am having a hard time testing that as it is hard to read data from server via telnet.

If you could point me to a reference for this that would be great as the php manual doesn't explain this scenario.

Comment: From my experience it looks like there is no way to get it back online except for restarting the php service. So I assume that after a failure you will have to manually sit down and handle the case, making sure everything works and then restart your application / php service. I would also be interested in automatic recovery, though, if anyone knows details.